# Error loading google maps for Android (Intellij)

Tags: android, google-maps, intellij-idea

I've been trying to create a project using IntelliJ to develop an Android application using google maps.  I have imported the google maps library into the project but whenever I accept all these changes and try to begin my project, I keep receiving the following error message on screen:

Could not save project:
java.io.IOException: Failed to create child file at C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\extras\google\google_play_services\libproject\google-play-services_lib\google-play-services_lib\google-play-services_lib.iml

If anyone could shed any light on this matter I'd be grateful - thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you import your google lib, at that time tick the checkbox of "copy into the project" so that google library can be copied into your workspace. Its all because sometimes our OS doesn't allows us to access files present in the c: . Hope you got my point.